# Angular: access data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

Just started learning angular and I'm stumped at the moment.

I don't understand how angular accesses DOM data.

In all examples I've seen data is being initialized inside a controller:

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
});
```

What if I have a table that's been filled from another source for example.

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <td> John </td>
        <td> johnson </td>
        <td> 30 </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> David </td>
        <td> Davidson </td>
        <td> 23 </td>
    </tr>

    ...

</table>
```

Let's say I want to do something with those table rows (filter some of them, for example) when a user clicks a certain button. How do I get all the data that's in a table in my controller.

I could apply a filter on a repeater like in the tutorial

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query">
   {{phone.name}}
   <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
</li>
```

but I don't load data from a controller like the tutorial does. In my case it's already there. I just need to get it for manipulation. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is, You can't. Angular can only manipulate data that's binded to the $scope from within a controller (or using ng-init, but the controller makes it easier).

Answer (score 1):

Angular does not access DOM to retrieve data, it accesses data you pass to it (usually inside the controller) and uses it to generate DOM.